# Advice in Using Nutch Content Limit

Tags: hadoop, web-crawler, nutch

I am using Nutch 2.1 in crawling an entire domain (company.com, for example). I once ran across this problem where I am not getting all the links I want crawled because of the content limit set in Apache Nutch. Usually, when I check the content, only the upper half of the page is stored in the database, and thus the links on the lower half were not being fetched.

In order to solve this, I changed the **nutch-site.xml** so that the content limit looks like this:

```
<property>
    <name>http.content.limit</name>
    <value>-1</value>
    <description>The length limit for downloaded content using the http
    protocol, in bytes. If this value is nonnegative (>=0), content longer
    than it will be truncated; otherwise, no truncation at all. Do not
    confuse this setting with the file.content.limit setting.
    </description>
</property>
```

Doing that solved the problem, but at some point, I am encountering an OutOfMemory error, as evidenced by **this output** upon parsing:

```
ParserJob: starting
ParserJob: resuming:    false
ParserJob: forced reparse:  false
ParserJob: parsing all
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.RuntimeException: job failed: name=parse, jobid=job_local_0001
at org.apache.nutch.util.NutchJob.waitForCompletion(NutchJob.java:54)
at org.apache.nutch.parse.ParserJob.run(ParserJob.java:251)
at org.apache.nutch.parse.ParserJob.parse(ParserJob.java:259)
at org.apache.nutch.parse.ParserJob.run(ParserJob.java:302)
at org.apache.hadoop.util.ToolRunner.run(ToolRunner.java:65)
at org.apache.nutch.parse.ParserJob.main(ParserJob.java:306)
```

Here is my **hadoop.log** (part near the error):

```
    2016-01-22 02:02:35,898 INFO  crawl.SignatureFactory - Using Signature impl: org.apache.nutch.crawl.MD5Signature
2016-01-22 02:02:37,255 WARN  util.NativeCodeLoader - Unable to load native-hadoop library for your platform... using builtin-java classes where applicable
2016-01-22 02:02:39,130 INFO  mapreduce.GoraRecordReader - gora.buffer.read.limit = 10000
2016-01-22 02:02:39,255 INFO  mapreduce.GoraRecordWriter - gora.buffer.write.limit = 10000
2016-01-22 02:02:39,322 INFO  crawl.SignatureFactory - Using Signature impl: org.apache.nutch.crawl.MD5Signature
2016-01-22 02:02:53,018 WARN  mapred.FileOutputCommitter - Output path is null in cleanup
2016-01-22 02:02:53,031 WARN  mapred.LocalJobRunner - job_local_0001
java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.reuseAndReadPacket(MysqlIO.java:3051)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.reuseAndReadPacket(MysqlIO.java:2991)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.checkErrorPacket(MysqlIO.java:3532)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.checkErrorPacket(MysqlIO.java:943)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.nextRow(MysqlIO.java:1441)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.readSingleRowSet(MysqlIO.java:2936)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.getResultSet(MysqlIO.java:477)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.readResultsForQueryOrUpdate(MysqlIO.java:2631)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.readAllResults(MysqlIO.java:1800)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.sqlQueryDirect(MysqlIO.java:2221)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.execSQL(ConnectionImpl.java:2624)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.PreparedStatement.executeInternal(PreparedStatement.java:2127)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.PreparedStatement.executeQuery(PreparedStatement.java:2293)
    at org.apache.gora.sql.store.SqlStore.execute(SqlStore.java:423)
    at org.apache.gora.query.impl.QueryBase.execute(QueryBase.java:71)
    at org.apache.gora.mapreduce.GoraRecordReader.executeQuery(GoraRecordReader.java:66)
    at org.apache.gora.mapreduce.GoraRecordReader.nextKeyValue(GoraRecordReader.java:102)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask$NewTrackingRecordReader.nextKeyValue(MapTask.java:532)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.MapContext.nextKeyValue(MapContext.java:67)
    at org.apache.hadoop.map
```

I only encountered this problemm when I set the content limit to -1. However, if I don't do that, there's a chance I won't get all my the links I wanted crawled. Any advice on how to use the content limit? Is doing that not really advisable? If so, what possible alternatives could I use? Thanks!

Comment: why do not you increase memory and see how it will work?

Comment: Is there a way to run Nutch with increased memory?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that you set the crawling depth to unlimited (-1). When your crawler system hits to heavy URLs such as `https://en.wikipedia.org, https://wikipedia.org and https://en.wikibooks.org`, your system may run out of Memory during the crawling process. You should increase memory for Nuch by setting NUTCH_HEAPSIZE environmental variable value `e.g., export NUTCH_HEAPSIZE=4000` (see details in the Nutch script). Note that this value is equivalent to Hadoop's HADOOP_HEAPSIZE. If it still doesn't work, you should increase the physical memory in your system ^ ^

Hope this helps,

Le Quoc Do